# Loading .RData files into Python

Tags: python, r, rdata

I have a bunch of .RData time-series files and would like to load them directly into Python without first converting the files to some other extension (such as .csv). Any ideas on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

People ask this sort of thing on the R-help and R-dev list and the usual answer is that the code is the documentation for the `.RData` file format. So any other implementation in any other language is **hard++**.

I think the only reasonable way is to install RPy2 and use R's `load` function from that, converting to appropriate python objects as you go. The `.RData` file can contain structured objects as well as plain tables so watch out.

Linky: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/

Quicky:

```
>>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>>> robjects.r['load'](".RData")
```

objects are now loaded into the R workspace.

```
>>> robjects.r['y']
<FloatVector - Python:0x24c6560 / R:0xf1f0e0>
[0.763684, 0.086314, 0.617097, ..., 0.443631, 0.281865, 0.839317]
```

That's a simple scalar, d is a data frame, I can subset to get columns:

```
>>> robjects.r['d'][0]
<IntVector - Python:0x24c9248 / R:0xbbc6c0>
[       1,        2,        3, ...,        8,        9,       10]
>>> robjects.r['d'][1]
<FloatVector - Python:0x24c93b0 / R:0xf1f230>
[0.975648, 0.597036, 0.254840, ..., 0.891975, 0.824879, 0.870136]
```

Comment: One useful comment to add: typically you will want to manipulate these objects in Numpy, so I would add the following: `from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri` and then `numpy2ri.ri2numpy(r['d'])`. You then have numpy arrays that you can manipulate in a "pythonic" way.

Comment: @jonathanrocher it seems these days (numpy 1.11.1) you can just do `np.array( r['d'] )` and I don't have `ri2numpy` in `numpy2ri` anymore.

Comment: Note: the documentation is now hosted on GithHub: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/ (the current link does not work)

Answer (score 95):

As an alternative for those who would prefer not having to install R in order to accomplish this task (r2py requires it), there is a new package "pyreadr" which allows reading RData and Rds files directly into python without dependencies.

It is a wrapper around the C library librdata, so it is very fast.

You can install it easily with pip:

```
pip install pyreadr
```

As an example you would do:

```
import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('/path/to/file.RData') # also works for Rds

# done! let's see what we got
# result is a dictionary where keys are the name of objects and the values python
# objects
print(result.keys()) # let's check what objects we got
df1 = result["df1"] # extract the pandas data frame for object df1
```

The repo is here: https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr

Disclaimer: I am the developer of this package.

Comment: KeyError: 'df1'

Comment: df1 is just a dummy example, you have to use a key from results.keys(). For issues please use the guthub repo issues.

Comment: Hi, I am struggling with this in Python 3.7.6. I installed with ```pip install readr``` and ```conda install -c conda-forge pyreadr ```. I managed to import RData into python as an ```OrderedDict``` but I cannot access the data inside. Even with a basic 3x2 RData file ```df.keys()``` yields ```odict_keys([None])```. Has something changed in Python or R that you need to update or am I missing something.

Comment: Please file an issue in the github if you have problems. Read carefully the Known limitations section in the Readme before. When submitting an issue post the code and file to reproduce the problem; otherwise I cannot help.

Comment: I'm getting error ```LibrdataError: Unable to convert string to the requested encoding``` when trying to read a ```.RData``` file. Different ```.RData``` files work, but the one with the data in the format I need doesn't load in, go figure! Any common reasons as to why this might happen?

Comment: right now pyreadr can handle only files saved in UTF-8. Yours probably is in some other encoding. There is an issue in github open about that error.

Comment: Would you mind having a look here? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72702702/batching-large-rfiles-in-pyreadr Thanks

Answer (score 9):

## Jupyter Notebook Users

If you are using Jupyter notebook, you need to do 2 steps:

Step 1: go to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2 and download Python interface to the R language (embedded R) in my case I will use `rpy2-2.8.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Put this file in the same working directory you are currently in.

Step 2: Go to your Jupyter notebook and write the following commands

```
# This is to install rpy2 library in Anaconda
!pip install rpy2-2.8.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

and then

```
# This is important if you will be using rpy2
import os
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'D:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rpy2'
```

and then

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
```

This should allow you to use R functions in python. Now you have to import the `readRDS` as follow

```
readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
df = readRDS('Data1.rds')
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df)
df.head()
```

Congratulations! now you have the Dataframe you wanted

However, I advise you to save it in pickle file for later time usage in python as

```
 df.to_pickle('Data1')
```

So next time you may simply use it by

```
df1=pd.read_pickle('Data1')
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, I couple years ago I had the same problem as you. I wanted to read `.RData` files from a library that I was developing. I considered using RPy2, but that would have forced me to release my library with a GPL license, which I did not want to do.

"pyreadr" didn't even exist then. Also, the datasets which I wanted to load were not in a standardized format as a `data.frame`.

I came to this question and read [Spacedman answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21288178). In particular, I saw the line

> So any other implementation in any other language is hard++.

as a challenge, and implemented the package [rdata](https://github.com/vnmabus/rdata) in a couple of days as a result. This is a very small pure Python implementation of a `.RData` parser and converter, able to suit my needs until now. The steps of parsing the original objects and converting to apropriate Python objects are separated, so that users could use a different conversion if they want. Moreover, users can add constructors for custom R classes.

This is an usage example:

```py
>>> import rdata

>>> parsed = rdata.parser.parse_file(rdata.TESTDATA_PATH / "test_vector.rda")
>>> converted = rdata.conversion.convert(parsed)
>>> converted
{'test_vector': array([1., 2., 3.])}
```

As I said, I developed this package and have been used since without problems, but I did not bother to give it visibility as I did not document it properly. This has recently changed and now the documentation is mostly ok, so here it is for anyone interested:

https://github.com/vnmabus/rdata

Comment: Worked for me without much overhead. You deserve a dual upvote :)

Comment: I think the "hard++" comment refers to that, as the code (in R) is the definition, the definition can change at any time.  Kudos (and upvote) for writing the library, but I hope you have an extensive suite of tests against the official R documentation.

Comment: I have tests loading all major kinds of R objects, and I (and others) use it continuously to load non-trivial datasets. So far I haven't found a dataset I can't load, but if anyone founds any I accept issues and I review them in a timely manner.

Answer (score 2):

There is a third party library called `rpy`, and you can use this library to load `.RData` files. You can get this via a `pip` install `pip instally rpy` will do the trick, if you don't have `rpy`, then I suggest that you take a look at how to install it. Otherwise, you can simple do:

```
from rpy import *
r.load("file name here")
```

## EDIT:

It seems like I'm a little old school there,s rpy2 now, so you can use that.

Comment: Still using `rpy`? That's groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @rsc05 that caters to the Notebook users worked for me, but apparently one of the functions[`df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df)`] has been deprecated and now it should be `df = pandas2ri.rpy2py(df)`.

So, the complete solution should look like :

```
# import the libraries
>> import rpy2.robjects as robjects
>> from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

#activate
>> pandas2ri.activate()

# create readRDS object
>> readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']

# read .rds using readRDS object
>> df = readRDS('sri_testing_data.rds')

# convert the data into native dataframe object 
>> df = pandas2ri.rpy2py(df)

#print the dataframe
>> df.head()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
!pip install pyreadr
```

Then

```
result = pyreadr.read_r('/content/nGramsLite.RData')

# objects
print(result.keys()) # let's check what objects we got
```

```
>>>odict_keys(['ngram1', 'ngram2', 'ngram3', 'ngram4'])
```

```
df1 = result["ngram1"]
```

```
df1.head()
```

Done!!