# I am having trouble reading RData using pyreadr

Tags: python, rdata

I have installed pyreadr and would like to use it to read .RData. I have followed the direction given from the previous comment on here [Loading RData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288133/loading-rdata-files-into-python) but that did not work for me.

When I try the following line (with the path pointing to the right file):

```
result = pyreadr.read_r('/path/to/file.RData')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/apps/bioapps/python/Python-3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyreadr/pyreadr.py", 
line 80, in list_objects
parser.parse(path)
File "pyreadr/librdata.pyx", line 117, in pyreadr.librdata.Parser.parse
File "pyreadr/librdata.pyx", line 142, in pyreadr.librdata.Parser.parse
pyreadr.custom_errors.LibrdataError: Unable to read from file
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work when you try the other answer (not pyreadr)? Are you 100% that the input file is okay?

Comment: You mean rpy2.robjects? If so, no I haven't tried. I clicked on the link that was given for the documentation and it never opened so I was a bit more inclined toward pyreadr.